# Apache Cassandra node restarts randomly

Tags: cassandra, java

I have a cluster of 11 nodes, `Apache Cassandra version 3.11.4`, where certain nodes are restarted at random times.

Nodes characteristics:

```
CPU(s):     32
Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4110 CPU @ 2.10GHz
RAM:        62G
Disk:       42T
```

Below, I am attaching system.log file of one node a.k.a node70 before restart:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:47] 2024-01-07 21:07:17,332 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:128274211 (203.247MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495387-big-Data.db
INFO  [HintsDispatcher:7] 2024-01-07 21:07:26,969 HintsStore.java:133 - Deleted hint file d75b9d99-e44b-4b91-8ba1-2b60852699da-1704638444850-1.hints
INFO  [HintsDispatcher:7] 2024-01-07 21:07:26,970 HintsDispatchExecutor.java:282 - Finished hinted handoff of file d75b9d99-e44b-4b91-8ba1-2b60852699da-1704638444850-1.hints to endpoint /10.147.49.69: d75b9d99-e44b-4b91-8ba1-2b60852699da
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:36] 2024-01-07 21:07:33,280 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:20755 (172.373MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495376-big-Data.db
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2024-01-07 21:07:55,185 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:128274211 (116.939MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495383-big-Data.db
...
```

I am leaving key logs, so you can follow up. Whole file contains a lot of `WARN`s about `Writing large patition`.

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:47] 2024-01-07 21:17:45,303 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:26300 (191.685MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495387-big-Data.db
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:40] 2024-01-07 21:18:00,395 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:26663181 (145.598MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495380-big-Data.db
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:42] 2024-01-07 21:18:14,510 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:39741453 (111.068MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495416-big-Data.db
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2024-01-07 21:18:41,355 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Some operations were slow, details available at debug level (debug.log)
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2024-01-07 21:18:55,742 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:332 (107.752MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495383-big-Data.db
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:44] 2024-01-07 21:18:57,684 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:770 (107.219MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495384-big-Data.db
```

Also here:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:44] 2024-01-07 21:22:19,816 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:30096898 (103.169MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495384-big-Data.db
INFO  [CompactionExecutor:42] 2024-01-07 21:22:26,206 NoSpamLogger.java:91 - Maximum memory usage reached (536870912), cannot allocate chunk of 1048576
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2024-01-07 21:22:57,513 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:26663181 (148.395MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495383-big-Data.db
INFO  [IndexSummaryManager:1] 2024-01-07 21:22:59,163 IndexSummaryRedistribution.java:77 - Redistributing index summaries
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:42] 2024-01-07 21:23:01,308 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:20755 (350.542MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495416-big-Data.db
```

These kind of logs are repeating till **2024-01-7 22:49:00** and node just goes down and ups:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2024-01-07 22:49:26,242 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:30269442 (109.637MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495383-big-Data.db
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:08,817 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,194 Config.java:496 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=null; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=LBS Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=null; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=32; concurrent_compactors=16; concurrent_counter_writes=16; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=16; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=16; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@7ec7ffd3; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_materialized_views=false; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=null; endpoint_snitch=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=null; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=true; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=10.147.49.70; listen_interface=null; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=172800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=1024; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=256; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=10.147.49.70; rpc_interface=null; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=null; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=10.147.49.69,10.147.49.70,10.147.49.71,10.147.49.74,10.147.49.75,10.147.49.73,10.147.49.72,10.147.49.67,10.147.49.68,10.147.49.64,10.147.49.65}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@5b239d7d; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,195 DatabaseDescriptor.java:373 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,196 DatabaseDescriptor.java:431 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 2508MB
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,196 DatabaseDescriptor.java:435 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 2508MB
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,252 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,252 DatabaseDescriptor.java:735 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,580 GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.java:64 - Loaded cassandra-topology.properties for compatibility
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,667 JMXServerUtils.java:246 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,675 CassandraDaemon.java:476 - Hostname: server70
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,676 CassandraDaemon.java:483 - JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_222
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,677 CassandraDaemon.java:484 - Heap size: 9.800GiB/9.800GiB
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,678 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 7550016(7373K) committed = 7602176(7424K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,678 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 20864080(20375K) committed = 21495808(20992K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,679 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2402776(2346K) committed = 2621440(2560K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,679 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 1718091776(1677824K) used = 481091008(469815K) committed = 1718091776(1677824K) max = 1718091776(1677824K)
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,679 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 214695936(209664K) used = 0(0K) committed = 214695936(209664K) max = 214695936(209664K)
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:09,679 CassandraDaemon.java:489 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 8589934592(8388608K) used = 0(0K) committed = 8589934592(8388608K) max = 8589934592(8388608K)
```

**NB!**

When I want to check nodetool status in node70 it shows me: **Cassandra 3.0 and later require Java 8u40 or later**, but others can display even their versions are same.
Also, for some reason Snapshots does not work on this node, and data from 2020 and 2021 is stored there, although I configured it for two years.

I am also getting such logs in logs directory:

```
hs_err_pid1461756.log
hs_err_pid1502594.log
```

Here is my **gc.logs**:

```
2024-01-08T11:38:48.267+0600: 3533.985: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0273467 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0017132 seconds
{Heap before GC invocations=5251 (full 22):
 par new generation   total 1887488K, used 1710170K [0x0000000540000000, 0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005c0000000)
  eden space 1677824K, 100% used [0x0000000540000000, 0x00000005a6680000, 0x00000005a6680000)
  from space 209664K,  15% used [0x00000005b3340000, 0x00000005b52d68f0, 0x00000005c0000000)
  to   space 209664K,   0% used [0x00000005a6680000, 0x00000005a6680000, 0x00000005b3340000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 8388608K, used 3626506K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 46509K, capacity 48029K, committed 48604K, reserved 1091584K
  class space    used 5645K, capacity 5969K, committed 6108K, reserved 1048576K
2024-01-08T11:38:48.753+0600: 3534.471: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2024-01-08T11:38:48.753+0600: 3534.471: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 107347968 bytes, new threshold 1 (max 1)
- age   1:   22025736 bytes,   22025736 total
: 1710170K->30151K(1887488K), 0.0262670 secs] 5336676K->3678067K(10276096K), 0.0266400 secs] [Times: user=0.46 sys=0.01, real=0.02 secs] 
Heap after GC invocations=5252 (full 22):
 par new generation   total 1887488K, used 30151K [0x0000000540000000, 0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000005c0000000)
  eden space 1677824K,   0% used [0x0000000540000000, 0x0000000540000000, 0x00000005a6680000)
  from space 209664K,  14% used [0x00000005a6680000, 0x00000005a83f1f70, 0x00000005b3340000)
  to   space 209664K,   0% used [0x00000005b3340000, 0x00000005b3340000, 0x00000005c0000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 8388608K, used 3647915K [0x00000005c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 46509K, capacity 48029K, committed 48604K, reserved 1091584K
  class space    used 5645K, capacity 5969K, committed 6108K, reserved 1048576K
}
2024-01-08T11:38:48.780+0600: 3534.498: Total time for which application threads were stopped: 0.0325483 seconds, Stopping threads took: 0.0013643 seconds
2024-01-08 11:38:49 GC log file has reached the maximum size. Saved as /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/logs/gc.log.0
```

Please, tell me if you need additional information. This is my first post in dba.stackexchange.com, so I may not take into account some forum rules
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in these 2 log entries:

```
WARN  [CompactionExecutor:43] 2024-01-07 22:49:26,242 BigTableWriter.java:211 - Writing large partition xxx/xxx:30269442 (109.637MiB) to sstable /home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/data/data/xxx/xxx-5d4d2290f19811e99de8956ff675a115/md-1495383-big-Data.db
INFO  [main] 2024-01-07 22:55:08,817 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:89 - Configuration location: file:/home/user/apache-cassandra-3.11.4/conf/cassandra.yaml
```

Notice that there is a 6-minute difference between the last log entry (at `22:49:26,242`) and when Cassandra was started (at `22:55:08,817`).

It would be safe to assume that the Cassandra process stopped at `22:49`. The first thing I would check is whether the node ran into an out-of-memory (OOM) error because it is suspicious that logging would just suddenly stop with no errors recorded.

In my experience, logging stops when the Cassandra process has been terminated either by an operator or a daemon/script/tool. Check that you don't have any monitoring tools/scripts running on the server that could have possibly terminated the Cassandra process. You can also check the operating system logs for the possibility that the `oom-killer` terminated the Java process. Cheers!